# Creating a simplified version of tr program from Unix system. Translating characters function

Tags: c, ascii, getchar

```
void Translating(const char set1[], char set2[])
{

    size_t q;
    int s;
    int c;
    unsigned char table[256];

   /*Creates a table to reference characters 
     by their ACII values based on,  
     their integer values in the ASCII table.*/

   for(s = 0; s < 256; s++)
   {
       table[s] = s;

#if 1
       /*Something is occurring here. 
         The values are not returning equal to*/ 
       /*what they should be.*/
       for(q = 0; set1[q] !='\0'; q++)
       {
           if(set2[q] != set1[q])
           table[(int)set1[q]] = set2[q];
       }
#endif

       while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
       {
           putchar(table[c]);
       }
   }
}
```

Below this code I have a working user interface(rough one) that pulls in values from command line arguments and saves them to set1 and set2. These values would typically be an array of characters(I have tested them they are being copied correctly). These characters need to be passed to this function and translated.

```
For example: `./a asd fgt < test.txt > grr.txt`
```

This would read in the text file test and change

```
all 'f' with 'a', 
all 'g' with 's' and 
all 't' with 'd'.
```

My function is very close to working however when I use it my values that are printed are crazy. 
As if my ASCII table has been increased by some random value like 100 or something. Thank you for you time if someone helps and anyone should try this program it's fun and challenging. 
Maybe I need to reset a certain value for my variables, C is a tricky beast.

Comment: May be this? (int)set1[q]

Comment: Your inner `while` should be moved outside the `for`

Answer (score 1):

```
   for(s = 0; s < 256; s++)
   {
       table[s] = s;
   }
   for(q = 0; set1[q] !='\0'; q++)
   {
       if(set2[q] != set1[q])
       table[(int)set1[q]] = set2[q];
   }
   while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
   {
       putchar(table[c]);
   }

put both inner `for` and `while` outside the outer `for` loop.

 - First you update the table with all the character list
 - change the character list to your needs.
 - Used the modified character code to print the output.
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Sridhar I appreciate the help. I got the program to run and school is very busy so I never looked back till now.